# Can I set my Windows to boot without stop on password verification even when having a password set?

Tags: windows-7, windows, passwords, user-accounts

Is there some way to configure Windows 7 to boot up without asking for a password (on password check phase) even if I have a password set on my account?

What I wan't to do with it, is boot up without interruptions, but when I lock my Windows (with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) I want to block it until I enter my account password.

I was wondering if maybe exists some registry set configuration of something like this.

Comment: IMHO "A locked Windows? Oh power off, power on and now I have access"  That's why you couldn't have a password only when you lock your Windows. ( Posted as comment, since I don't know, there's maybe a way to do it)

Comment: While I think there may be some way to do this (I don't know of one, though) I agree with @Nettogrof that it's totally insecure and pointless.

Comment: Actually, the true history is that I erased my account password because I put a password on BIOS to start booting Windows, so, if I left a password active on Windows, I would need to insert two passwords to boot Windows... Without a password, windows lock do not require a password to enter, so my machine would be unprotected. With this situation, I insert password protection to boot jusr 1 second after turning on my machine and still have lock screen password protection, I win on boot time, if I made myself understandable....

Comment: @shinrai: certainly insecure, but not at all pointless. Security is frequently not much of a concern: not everybody puts stuff on their computer that they feel they need to hide.

Comment: @DiogoRocha - Now that setup makes sense :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open a run box <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type in

> control userpasswords2

Uncheck "users must enter a user name and password to use this computer", highlight the user account you wish to log on automatically before going to the next step.

[image]

Then click the Advanced Tab and be sure "Require users to pres ctrl+alt+del" box is Unchecked then hit apply.

[image]

Enter the user account name and password for the account you wish to log on automatically and hit the Ok button. Close user accounts window. (If you highlighted the correct user count as suggested earlier it will automatically be filled in)

[image]

It will now log on using the account and password you set, using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will still require a password to log back on.

Comment: @DiogoRocha You are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep your password, but still automatically login on boot, you can do it by setting a registry key:

> HKLM -> SOFTWARE -> Microsoft -> Windows NT -> CurrentVersion -> Winlogon

You need to set the `DefaultUserName`, `DefaultPassword`, and `DefaultDomain` string values to match your login information, and set the `AutoAdminLogon` string value to "`1`". If any of these values do not exist, you will need to create them.