# Auto Logon Windows 7 Upon Initial Boot While Still Protected by Password

Tags: windows-7, boot, passwords, user-accounts, automation

I have a Windows 7 machine currently. I am writing a script which will always be running. Basically, it checks to make sure a program is open, and if it's not, it opens it.

However, when my computer reboots when I'm not around, let's say due to windows updates. My computer turns back on, but idles at the login screen.

I would like my Windows 7 machine to automatically log into a specific account upon initial system boot up, but still keep a password on the account, so once the machine is booted up and logged in, can later be password protected still from switching user accounts or locking the computer.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: I found a solution: [Can I set my Windows to boot without stop on password verification even when having a password set?](http://superuser.com/a/405941/216639)

Comment: Also seems similar to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/352616/windows-7-automatically-login-and-lock

Answer (score 2):

There is also the Sysinternals tool that does the same thing as Simon's suggestion (And "encrypts" the password.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963905.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. Press the <kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on your keyboard to launch the “Run” dialog box.
2. Type `regedit` and hit enter to open the Registry Editor
3. Then browse to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\`
4. Set `AutoAdminLogon  = 1` (create it if doesn't exist its a string variable)
5. Set `DefaultUserName = your username` (create it if doesn't exist its a string variable)
6. Set `DefaultPassword = your password` (create it if doesn't exist its a string variable)

I don't recommend such a solution as someone could simply force the computer to shut down by pressing the power button and start it again and would be logged in with your account!

Comment: (-1) use the way from *AthomSfere*. In your case the data are not encrypted.