# How to log in into a user account that a password with a batch file? Or any other settings?

Tags: windows, boot, passwords, auto-login, autologon

I think I've seen this before but I've never given it much consideration.

I usually do not have a password for my own user account, and it's the default one. I set up an automatic boot on BIOS setup and it does that every morning, and automatically logs on into my user account and different batch files then run due to some scheduler settings.

However, I now have to use a password on my user account. But I want my computer to log in into my user account each time it boots even though there's a password. How can that be done with a batch file or any other means? Also, can it just log in automatically just on initial boot and not when I lock it manually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Windows 7 allow auto-login with a stored password, like TweakUI did?](http://superuser.com/questions/243681/does-windows-7-allow-auto-login-with-a-stored-password-like-tweakui-did), [Can I set my Windows to boot without stop on password verification even when having a password set?](http://superuser.com/questions/405933/can-i-set-my-windows-to-boot-without-stop-on-password-verification-even-when-hav), perhaps also see: [Automatically login and lock](http://superuser.com/questions/352616/automatically-login-and-lock)

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice way with registry keys to do this. Here are some instructions from this website: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/windows7/windows7_auto_logon.htm

I used the following steps at work and it works fine. (sorry for formatting, see above link for more readable version):

**Instructions to Enable Auto Logon with Regedit Launch Regedit.**

1. Navigate to: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\winlogon
2. Set: AutoAdminLogon = 1 (one means on, zero means off.)
3. Crucial Point set the Administrator's password.
4. Create a new String Value called DefaultPassword
5. Set: DefaultPassword = "P@ssw0rd"
6. Check for the existence of a REG_SZ called DefaultUserName.  The value should reflect the user who you wish to logon automatically.  If this value does not exist, then right-click in the right pane, New, REG_SZ, name it, DefaultUserName.
7. Set the string value to the required UserName. Optional Item: If your Windows 7 Machine has joined a domain, then create a String Value called DefaultDomainName.
8. Set: DefaultDomainName = "OnlyYouKnowDomain"

> Here is a summary of the four registry settings to enable Auto Logon
>
> AutoAdminLogon = "1" Enabled  (To disable Auto Logon set to value to
>   zero) DefaultUserName = "xxx"  DefaultPassword = "xxxx0xxxx" 
>   DefaultDomainName = "xxx.xxx".  Only needed if computer has joined a
>   domain.